# Find limit of function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Can someone show me how to find this limit?

$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\cos \left(n^{2}\right)}{4+n^{3}+\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Comment: look, n ^ 3 grows faster than Cos [n ^ 2]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
Limit[Cos[n^2]/(4 + n^3 + Sqrt[n]), n -> Infinity]
(*0*)
```